# How to follow prefix number according the table contain value to change the color show in the page?

Tags: php, css, html-table

I am created the table to show the data from the database table in the page. My problem is how to follow prefix number according the table contain value to change the color show in the page?

Below is my output:
[image: output]

Below is my coding:

```html
<tbody>
                            <?php
                            $sql_wtp = "select * from  filing_code_management";
                            $query_wtp = db_conn_select($sql_wtp);
                            foreach ($query_wtp as $rs_wtp) {
                                if ($rs_wtp['status'] == 1) {
                                    $active = 'Active';
                                } elseif ($rs_wtp['status'] == 0) {
                                    $active = 'Inactive';
                                }
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>" . (++$no) . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['name'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['folder_location'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['category'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['request_by'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['date_request'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $active . "</td>";
                                if ($module_user_permission['edit'] == 1) {
                                    echo '<td><a href="#wtp_modal" onclick="select_(\'' . md5($rs_wtp['id'].$md5) . '\',\'wtp_content\')" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="Help" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-color-format="hex">Update</a>';
                                    if ($rs_wtp['status'] == 1) {
                                            echo '<a onclick="delete_(\'' . md5($rs_wtp['id'].$md5) . '\',1)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-color-format="hex">Deactivate</a>';
                                        } elseif ($rs_wtp['status'] == 0) {
                                            echo '<a onclick="delete_(\'' . md5($rs_wtp['id'].$md5) . '\',0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-color-format="hex">Activate</a>';
                                        }
                                    echo '</td>';
                                }
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
```

I want the prefix number follow below the number of range:

```html
Prefix number |      Color 
--------------------------
100 until 199 |      Blue
200 until 299 |      Red
300 until 399 |      Yellow
400 until 499 |      Orange
500 until 599 |      Green
```

Actually I want the output same like below the sample picture, below the sample picture is not using coding to make it, just I am used the paint software to edit and make it easy to let yours understand what I want to get the output:

[image: Output 2]
Hope someone can guide me or give me some ideas to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: For a starter, a simple `if` construct would do it. Maybe create css classes for the colors and a function to return a class based on the input/parameter. Apply the function/css class to where you need it

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks. Can you show me sample to do it?

Comment: Code sample for an `if` construct? You already have `if`s in that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of constant things in your problem.

1. All of your subcategories start with a number, ie: 100, 200, 300, 300-1, etc...
2. You have a rule that sets numerical values as potential index for color values that correspond to those values. ie: 100-199 = blue, 200-299 = red, etc...

You can use a bracket at the end of your variable to get the first character of your string. So, with that said, knowing that your values for each color fall into numeric values that hold constant with the first number in the string of numbers being the same, ie: 100, or 102 or 134, or 178 or 199, all of these are always blue, you can use that method to get the first character of your string ($variable) and compare it to an array of potential values of colors with keys set to those corresponding rules for index of color.

See my example below:

```php
$valuetocheck = "299-45 PENTADBIRAN"; // --> I believe this would be $rs_wtp['name'] correct?

//--> This can be placed anywhere on the page above the foreach loop
$colors = array (
    "1" => "blue",   //--> for all colors within the range of 100-199
    "2" => "red",    //--> for all colors within the range of 200-299
    "3" => "yellow", //--> for all colors within the range of 300-399
    "4" => "purple", //--> for all colors within the range of 400-499
    "5" => "green"   //--> for all colors within the range of 500-599
);
$stmt = null; //--> NULL variable to hold the concatenated values and display in your echo

//--> place the following foreach loop right after you define `$rs_wtp`, 
foreach($rs_wtp['name'] as $name => $valuetocheck){
    //--> Get the first character of the string, which will be the number that id's the color
    $check = $valuetocheck[0];
    //--> start the div that will style your text, or set a class            
    $stmt .= '<div style="color:'; 
    //--> Iterate over the color array to find the right color
    foreach ($colors as $key => $color){ 
        //--> compare the first character against the $key value 
        //--> within $colors array each iteration through the $rs_wtp array
        if($check == $key){
            $stmt .= $color;  //--> Concatenate $stmt 
        }
    }$stmt .= ';">'.$valuetocheck.'</div>'; //--> Close style attribute and div tag
}

echo $stmt; //-> place this in the <td> tag that holds the `$rs_wtp['name'] in  your code`
```

Fiddle: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9938a5e6a88de29511d22458a23a39b3a2368995

**EDIT** *4/22/20:*

Place the following define, we will be defining the color array and turning it into a constant so the scope is global.

Then create a function that will iterate over your names and folder_locations and place them in a styled span tag, then place the span tag into the echo block for each item respectively.

```
// the following constant will now be global again place this and the function above your query or in a defines page if you use one.

define("COLORS", array(
    1 => "blue",   //--> for all colors within the range of 100-199
    2 => "red",    //--> for all colors within the range of 200-299
    3 => "yellow", //--> for all colors within the range of 300-399
    4 => "purple", //--> for all colors within the range of 400-499
    5 => "green")   //--> for all colors within the range of 500-599    
);  

function changeColor($value){
    $stmt = null;
    $rs_wtp_name = $value; 
    $check = $rs_wtp_name[0]; // get the first character in the string
    foreach (COLORS as $key => $color){ 
        //--> compare the first character against the $key value 
        //--> within $colors array each iteration through the $rs_wtp array
        if($check == $key){
            $stmt .= $color;  //--> Concatenate $stmt 
        }
    }

    $output = "<span style='color:".$stmt.";'>" . $rs_wtp_name . "</span>";
    return $output;
}
```

Now in your code... This should work for you how your code is written. I can not test with your query though.

```
 $sql_wtp = "select * from  filing_code_management";
 $query_wtp = db_conn_select($sql_wtp);
      foreach ($query_wtp as $rs_wtp) {
           if ($rs_wtp['status'] == 1) {
                $active = 'Active';
           } elseif ($rs_wtp['status'] == 0) {
                $active = 'Inactive';
           }
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td>" . (++$no) . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . changeColor($rs_wtp['name']) . "</td>";//<- here
           echo "<td>" . changeColor($rs_wtp['folder_location']) . "</td>";//<-- here
           echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['category'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['request_by'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['date_request'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $active . "</td>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. $rs_wtp['name'] correct. Then how to put your code to modify inside my code?

Comment: @Ong See my updated answer. This should do it for you. I made a test array: `$rs_wtp = array( 'name' => array(  '100-1 Sometext', '233-1 Sometext', '500 Sometext' )` the test resulted in exactly what you want, colored text that corresponds with the rules to color scheme you set forth as per 100-199, 200-299, 300-399 etc...

Comment: Your test array can show the correct correct. But I am not sure how to combine your code to my coding in the table. Can you show guide me?

Comment: @Ong see my edit, I changed a few things to accommodate how your code is written. Should work for you.

Comment: Thanks @dale landry. Finally can work. $rs_wtpname your side less to add _ . You remember edit it.

Comment: @Ong Whoops, thanks for pointing out the typo, changed it... Glad that worked out for you!

Comment: You are genius.

Comment: I have a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61363615/how-to-add-strikethrough-in-the-js-tree-according-condition . If you know how to solve it, you can answer. Thanks.